# Read first line of a raw text

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, pastebin

Hey Im using my little scraper and I want to save results with one detail, first line of a raw pastebin/any other bin webpage.

lets say I have this code:

```
r=requests.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/qH03hKGU") #random link
text=r.text
```

I want to get the first line of the variable text without saving it (I will save just the one line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `partition('\n')[0]` to get the first line:

```
import requests

r=requests.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/qH03hKGU") #random link
text=r.text

print(text.partition('\n')[0])
OUT: import glob
```

Comment: thanks, I'll find use for that in alot of my codes